# i want to create a loop which can find white spaces in a sting and then do processing on the string

Tags: string, loops, whitespace, oracle-sqldeveloper

So consider the string to be  Y = ABCD EFG AIJ
Now, Z<sub>1</sub>, Z<sub>2</sub> and Z<sub>3</sub> are say three lines in the loop.

1. so the loop should work in a way that it first identifies the white space i.e. X<sub>1</sub> = 5 and then next statement should be substring(Y, 1, X<sub>1</sub>-1); and the output will be:- 
   Z<sub>1</sub> = ABCD
2. second statement should identify the second white space for i.e. X<sub>2</sub> = 9 and again the second statement should be
   substring(Y, X<sub>1</sub>+1,X<sub>2</sub>-1); and the output should be 
   Z<sub>2</sub> = EFG

and so on.

Once we have Z<sub>1</sub>, Z<sub>2</sub> and Z<sub>3</sub>
i want to compare first character of Z<sub>1</sub> with Z<sub>2</sub> and reorder the text in my string.

For Eg

if; A > E then reorder and replace A with E
if; A < E then same order.

Could anyone please help.

Comment: You didn't say in which language you would program this. In python, you can get the list of words like this: Z = Y.split(). The rest of the processing you want to do is unclear.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I want to do it in oracle

Comment: Add the right tag to your question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want ? -

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "abcd efg aij";
    System.out.println(str);
    int len = str.length();
    int[] pos = new int[len];
    for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
        if(str.charAt(j) == ' '){
            pos[j] = j;
        }else{
            pos[j] = -1;
        }
    }
    str = str.replace(" ","");
        int[] arr = new int[str.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
        }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    String str1="";
    for (int number : arr) {
        str1+=Character.toString ((char) number);

        }

    for(int k =0; k<str1.length(); k++){

        if(pos[k] != -1){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print(str1.charAt(k));
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java String class has split method so you can simply say

```
//arr will have multiple items - arr[0]="ABCD";arr[1]="EFG";arr[2]="AIJ"
String[] arr = Y.split(" ");
```

now i want to understand what do you mean by line :-

if; A > E then reorder and replace A with E if; A < E then same order.
do you want to sort this ?

Comment: by that i mean i want to compare the first character of arr[0] with arr[1] and if ascii value of character in arr[0] is greater than arr[1] then replace both characters with each other.

Comment: nice--
if you have input - "ABCD ABCDE ABCDEF"
what is your expected result from above string ?